# nano editor from terminal app GNUroot in an android cellphone S4

Tags: android

im using nano editor in my android cellphone through GNUroot, since the keyboard doenst have the key "Ctrl" How am i supose to save and exit??
It seems that by pressing "plus volume" and "e" it goes through a comand mode but still cant find the save and exit option.thanks for the time

Answer (score 4):

I use Termux an Android terminal emulator where you use the volume up key as ctrl key see here: https://termux.com/touch-keyboard.html